MapStruct not generating implementation
I am  using Java  17,Gradle  as build tool, the following is my gradle dependency
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'


I am trying to  understand  MapStruct , but when gradle  build,bootRun is called  MapStruct is not generating any implementation
Here  is the  code:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SimpleMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "name",target="name")
    @Mapping(source = "totalCount",target="count")
    SimpleDto mapToDto(SimpleRO ro);
}


SimpleDto.java
public class SimpleDto {
    private String name;
    private String count;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}

SimpleRO.java
public class SimpleRO {
    private String name;
    private String totalCount;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }

    public void setTotalCount(String totalCount) {
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }
}



You must register org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final as an annotation processor, not as an implementation dependency as you do now. See https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/#gradle for the correct gradle configuration.

Only adding the dependency will not hook mapstruct into the build process, that's what the annotationProcessor statement does.

According to the MapStruct Installation Documentation you have to include mapstruct as a dependency but also as annotationProcessor in your build.gradle. Like
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'

    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
}

In the file you showed, the second part (mapstruct-processor) was also given as implementation instead of annotationProcessor.
